# Can a method have multiple returns of different types?

Tags: java, android

In short i have a method which selects a random operation and generates two random numbers, it then creates an expression out of them as a string and changes a textview to show that expression as show here:

```
public String Nov2()
{
    String[] ops = new String[] {" + ", " - ", " * ", " / "};
    int i = rand.nextInt(4-0) + 0;
    String op1 = ops[i];

    int novnum1 = rand.nextInt(101-1) + 1;

    int novnum2 = rand.nextInt(101-1) + 1;

    String nov2Exp = novnum1 + op1 + novnum2 + " = ";

    setContentView(R.layout.gameview);

    TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.exp);

    display.setText(nov2Exp);

    return nov2Exp;
}
```

I have a second method which will put a number as a string into a second textview depending on which button is pressed:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View c) {

    switch (c.getId()) 
    {
        case R.id.keypad_1:
            TextView prs1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans);
            if (prs1.getText().equals("?"))
            {
                prs1.setText("1");
            }
            else
            {
            prs1.append("1");
            }

            break;
```

What i need is that when the user pushes another button the answer to expression will be calculated and compared with the contents of the answer textview, i've done some research on maths expression parsing and its proving far too complex for me to implement. Would i need to somehow return mutliple variables of different types from my method or am completely wrong? Can anyone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a custom data type:

```
public class Result {
    private String result1;
    private int result2;
    // etc.
}
```

and have your method return an object of this type.

Edit:

Well you can do something like:

```
public int Nov2()
{
    char[] ops = new char[] {'+', '-', '*', '/'};
    int i = rand.nextInt(4-0) + 0;
    char op1 = ops[i];

    int novnum1 = rand.nextInt(101-1) + 1;

    int novnum2 = rand.nextInt(101-1) + 1;

    int result = 0;

    switch(op1) {
        case '+': result = novnum1 + novnum2; break;
        case '-': result = novnum1 - novnum2; break;
        case '*': result = novnum1 * novnum2; break;
        case '/': result = novnum1 / novnum2; break;
    }

    String nov2Exp = novnum1 + " " + op1 + " " + novnum2 + " = ";

    setContentView(R.layout.gameview);

    TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.exp);

    display.setText(nov2Exp);

    return result;
}
```

This method will generate you a new expression, put it on the screen and then return the result. You can store it somewhere and when the user clicks the button compare it with his input.

Comment: What exactly would be done inside this class? I dont see how this helps me.

Comment: @nexus490: Well you said you needed to return both a String and an int right?

Comment: Ultimately what i need to do is calculate the expression the method generates and compares it to what the user enters, I have no idea how to acomplish this, i suppose what im asking is whether returning multiple data types is what i need to.

Comment: I don't understand what returning multiple types has to do with calculating a math expression. Do you want to both return the result and the string of the expression?

Comment: Ok forget about the multiple return types, it seems its me misunderstanding what i need to do. The first method i have will generate a random maths expression eg. "3 + 4 =" as a string and put it on a text view, the second method will put another string into a second textview depending on which button the user presses eg. "1". When the user pushes another button the app needs to check if the contents of the answer textview is the same as the actual result of 3+4 which would be 7.

Comment: Ok, i can see what you're suggesting. My next problem is i'm unsure how to use the return of that method inside another method.

Comment: @nexus490: Well in the main view class, you can have a member of type int, used as a temporary storage. Call this method that I posted to generate the expression and store the result inside that temporary int. Then, when the user clicks the button, the value inserted will be compared to the temporary int.

Comment: I define an integer variable and inside the method i add a line which takes the result of the calculation and assigns it to the temporary integer. When i try to add this integer to the textview on a button press i get a fatal error. i'll include it above.

Comment: It was a problem with type conversion.

Answer (score 2):

> Can a method have multiple returns

Yes.

> of different types?

It depends. Only if all of the types the method returns are instances of the declared return type. That is, the method returns objects with the same type, or a subtype of, the declared return type.

I don't see what this has to do with the body of the question, though.

Comment: Well i thought if i actually worked out the expression the method generates within the method itself, but the method returns a string, the result of the expression would be an integer. Do you see my problem?

Answer (score 0):

An observation: from looking at your Nov2() method, I'd suggest splitting the logic into separate methods as its currently performing the calculation and updating the display. Looks like trying to do too much in one method to me, which could be leading to confusion.